# Django: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'session'

Tags: django, session

i have my `view` method like this:

```
def name(request, name='prabhu'):
    response = HttpResponse("Name ==== %s " % name)
    response.set_cookie('name',name)    
    response.session['name'] = name
    return response
```

and `url` is

```
url(r'^name/(?P<name>[a-z\-]+)/$',views.name, name = 'name'),
```

so when i call http://localhost:8000/myapp/name/sample/ from browser i was expecting my session and cookie ['name'] to be set 'sample'. Instead it gives  **`'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'session'`**. cookies are fine but session is not working. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not surprising since it's [HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.session) that has the session attribute provided that the session middleware has been enabled.

[HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/http/response/#HttpResponse) does not have a session attribute but does have a cookies attribute but it's better to use sessions rather than juggle those cookies direct.